# Autoopen SearchView in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I have this code:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat
                .getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search");
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return true;
    }
```

It has SearchView. In order to open that SearchView, loop icon should be clicked. How to make it open automatically on the start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call this when you want to expand your searchview

```
searchItem.expandActionView();
```

Note that it is *searchItem* , not *searchView* .